# How can I list all emails in sorted order using nodejs with gmail API?

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

```
function listmessages(userId,auth,cb) {     
    gmailClass.users.messages.list({   
        auth: auth,   
        userId: userId,     
    },cb);    
}
```

Comment: sort by what ??

Comment: by received date

Answer (score 1):

Try using this [Users.messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages). From there, you will be able to get the "internalDate"

Note for "internalDate":

> The internal message creation timestamp (epoch ms), which determines
>   ordering in the inbox. For normal SMTP-received email, this represents
>   the time the message was originally accepted by Google, which is more
>   reliable than the Date header. However, for API-migrated mail, it can
>   be configured by client to be based on the Date header.

then, you can use the implementation by [Phrogz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405017/phrogz) from the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date).